# Structuring a before/after conditional

Tags: language-agnostic, structure

When I need a conditional to determine whether a block before or after a statement gets executed, this always leads to repeated code. I either end up with evaluating the condition twice, or repeating the block of code.

Even if this block is just a single *function call*, it doesn't exactly add to readability.

```
if( condition ) {
    BLOCK-A
}

BLOCK-B

if ( !condition ) {
    BLOCK-C
}
```

or

```
if( condition ) {
    BLOCK-A
    BLOCK-B
} else {
    BLOCK-B
    BLOCK-C
}
```

Is there a clearer way to structure code like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your options I would do it this way:

```
if( condition ) {
    BLOCK-A
    BLOCK-B
} else {
    BLOCK-B
    BLOCK-C
}
```

This will avoid evaluating the condition multiple times as you state in your question.

However, ideally I would try and avoid this kind of structuring all together as it couples the code up and can make changes further down the line difficult. Someone could change something in BLOCK-B for example in one place and not in another. Possibly moving `Block-B` into it's own function/method etc would be prudent.

**Personally I would do something like this**

```
function BlockB()
{
    //code from block b
}

function FirstCondition()
{
    //BLOCK-A code
    BlockB()
}

function SecondCondition()
{
    //BLOCK-C code
    BlockB()
}

if( condition ) {
    FirstCondition()
} else {
    SecondCondition()
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, even if block B is a function call, it doesn't look super-readable.

Comment: On reflection, I've edited it to how I think I would personally write that code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like BLOCK-B has two similar uses. Consider abstracting it out into its own area

```
function D {
   BLOCK-B
   }


if( condition ) {
    BLOCK-A
    function D
} else {
    function D
    BLOCK-C
}
```